# Negative of SVG curved <Path>

Tags: html, css, svg, bezier

I'm having a heck of time creating the negative of this svg/path curve.

What I'd like is the white to be the filled part described by the `<path>`, and the blue to be transparent to the element behind - exactly the opposite of the current depiction.

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated!

http://jsfiddle.net/CG_Pilot/0nw862zf/6/

```
<svg class="curveDownColor curveDown" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="50" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <path d="M0 0 C 50 100 80 100 100 0 Z"></path>
</svg>
```

With this CSS:

```
.curveDownColor {
    fill: blue;
    stroke: yellow;
    stroke-width: 3px;
    border: 2px dashed green;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CG_Pilot/0nw862zf/2/embedded/result/

Comment: You would like the blue path to be transparent and the curve blue? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: this might solve your problem : http://jsfiddle.net/vmjhw7z2/

Comment: Do you mean like this? http://jsfiddle.net/defghi1977/xza05sco/

Comment: @defghi1977 exactly!  Thanks so much! I'm new to using svg/path - so thanks.  If you re-post as an answer I'll mark it as correct.  If you care to see your assistance in action, I will be implementing the curves [on this project](http://www.intuitivebythesea.com) Regards, Zephyr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, like this? http://jsfiddle.net/0nw862zf/8

All I did was simply add the box boundaries to the path here. So instead of `Z` at the end of your path, make the path follow the boundary with `L 100 100, L 0 100`, *then* `Z`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The svg has viewBox, so we can wrap the path shape by rect path to invert fill area.
(sometimes needs fill-rule attribute.)

```
<svg class="curveDownColor curveDown" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="50" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <path d="M-100,-100h300v300h-300zM0 0 C 50 100 80 100 100 0 Z"></path>
</svg>
```